# Get all results of a NSFetchRequest in an NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchrequest, nsentitydescription

In my app I do this thing to abtain all specific value from an entity

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[self sharedAppDelegate] managedObjectContext];
NSError *error = nil;
NSFetchRequest *req = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Structure"];
[req setPropertiesToFetch:@[@"id_str"]];
[req setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];

NSArray *id_str_BD = [context executeFetchRequest:req error:&error];
```

int this way I obtain a `NSArray` of `NSDictionary`ies but I want directly an array of values.
What's a fast way to obtain it without loops?

Comment: An array of what values? The individual values of the `id_str` attribute?

Comment: @TomHarrington I guess the OP would retrieve an array of `id_str` values..but maybe I'm wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Tom. What values?

Anyway, you can accomplish it through KVC. For example,

```
NSFetchRequest* fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Structure"];
[fetchRequest setPropertiesToFetch:@[@"id_str"]];

NSArray* results = [[self managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];
NSArray* ids = [results valueForKey:@"id_str"];

NSLog(@"%@", ids);
```

**NOTES**

- Do not pass `nil` for the error. **ALWAYS** check for a possible error (for the sake of simplicity I don't use it in this code snippet)
- I would rename `id_str` to `idStructure`